# Redux saga. How to put action using addEventListener?

Tags: redux-saga, saga

How to put action using addEventListener?

Here is example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-state-new-array-forked-t84l9?file=/src/redux/sagas/sagas.js

```
function* someFunc() {
// yield put(action)
}

addEventListener('event', *---what's this should be?---*)
```

Comment: Do you mean that your payload is an eventListener? This is quite a good resource on [sagas](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/#demystifying-your-first-redux-saga) What are you looking to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, most addEventListener events are connected to some UI so you would just listen for the event in your component and then dispatch an action to get the data into a saga.

However, in case you really need to listen for some event directly in sagas you can use an [eventChannel](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels/#using-the-eventchannel-factory-to-connect-to-external-events) for that purpose.

It would end up looking something like this:

```js
function* someFunc(event) {
    // ...
}

function* rootSaga() {
    const clickChannel = eventChannel((emitter) => {
        document.addEventListener('click', emitter);
        return () => document.removeEventListener('click', emitter);
    });
    yield takeEvery(clickChannel, someFunc);
}
```

You can see both the component and direct approach implemented here to test it out:
https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions67683057redux-saga-how-to-put-action-using-addeventlistener-62rtr?file=/src/index.js:555-884

I use the component approach to store a name in store and the direct approach to save mouse coordinates.

Comment: And one more moment, how to give some arguments to someFunc?

Comment: @HackerMF what do you have in mind? If it's something in time of the event you can do `document.addEventListener('click', (ev) => emitter(ev, 'another arg'))`. If it is something you have in the root saga then you can do `yield takeEvery(clickChannel, someFunc, 'another arg')`.

Comment: As I got it for a while
document.addEventListener('click', () => emitter(JSON.stringify(args)));

Comment: I think the `clickChannel` can be defined outside the function.